# Select which has the latest date for each item

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, let say tableA and tableB.

Table A

```
create table tableA
(ID int, DocumentDate datetime2, DocumentName varchar(3), ItemID int);

insert into tableA (ID, DocumentDate, DocumentName, ItemID)
values (1, '2019-08-01 12:00:00', 'A-1', 1),
(2, '2020-05-12 13:00:00', 'B-2', 1),
(3, '2021-07-01 14:00:00', 'C-3', 1),
(4, '2020-01-01 12:00:00', 'D-4', 2),
(5, '2021-02-01 13:00:00', 'E-5', 2),
(6, '2021-07-02 14:00:00', 'F-6', 2);
```

and this is table B

```
create table tableB
(ID int, ItemCode varchar(3));

insert into tableB (ID, ItemCode)
values (1, 'AAA'),
(2, 'BBB');
```

here is my SQL Server query

```
select 
    A.ID, 
    A.DocumentDate, 
    A.DocumentName, 
    B.ItemCode 
from tableA A
left join tableB B on B.ID = A.ItemID
```

and the result [should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlI6d.png)

I want to select the 3rd one for AAA and the 6th one for BBB, which has the latest date.
Thank You.

Comment: "and the result should be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlI6d.png)"? This is the result you are getting with your query (all six rows). Don't you just want two of them? Your next paragraph seems to say so. And please don't use images. Paste the table in text format into your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply`:

```
select b.*, a.*
from tableB b outer apply
     (select top (1) a.*
      from tableA a
      where a.itemId = b.Id
      order by a.documentdate desc
     ) a;
```

With an index on `tableA(item, documentdate)`, this would often have very good performance

Answer (score 1):

Seems simple enough:

```sql
WITH cteDocuments As
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        DocumentDate,
        DocumentName,
        ItemID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY DocumentDate DESC) As RN
    FROM
        tableA
)
SELECT
    A.ID,
    A.DocumentDate,
    A.DocumentName,
    B.ItemCode
FROM
    cteDocuments As A
    LEFT JOIN tableB As B ON B.ID = A.ItemID
WHERE
    A.RN = 1
;
```

[ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql)